# Checking my MongoDB and getting an unusual dbs

Tags: django, mongodb

So today I was in my MongoDB and I type in `show dbs`. Other than my usual dbs there is an additional `hacked_by_unistellar`. Anyone might know what I can do here? It sounds like I have been hacked unless this is some terrible easter egg I have come across. Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: We had the same problem today on our MongoDB. A database has appeared called "hacked_by_unistellar".
What were your circumstances? Do you have logs?

Comment: My whole database has been cleaned out. My logs don't show anything out of the ordinary and up to about 2 hrs ago.

Comment: How do you plan on moving forward?

Comment: Same here, all my dbs are gone.

Comment: The weird thing is that we have no link between us. 
I think there may have been a zero-day.
Which host are you staying with?

EDIT : this article (https://kiber.blog.hu/2019/05/09/nyitott_mongodb_hacked_by_unistellar?utm_medium=doboz&utm_campaign=bloghu_cimlap&utm_source=tech) was posted today and he says that our mongo has no identifiers. It's my case.

Answer (score 1):

you should close your default mongoDB Port 27017. Got the same problem

Answer (score 1):

I had the same on an old backup server as well.

All I can say is that it is not related to an open, public mongodb port. The mongo server is running on localhost only, but has no access password (under FreeBSD 12).

Obviously, running with a public default port and no password is just what it is, but that's not the answer.

The only ports open on the server is SSH, 80/443 (running Apache 2.4.x) and a node service at port 3xxx, along with Mongo Express (also password protected).

There is also a MySQL server installed with no password, bound to localhost only, but that remained untouched.

It seems more likely that this is a vulnerability somewhere else, that is exploiting a non-protected local connection to mongodb.

Password protecting mongo might protect the database, but does not identify the point of access, which is worrisome.

Answer (score 1):

All of my data is gone!

Well, my only action now is to close any more open connections to my DB instance. My database required a password to access (so, being passwordless was not the issue).

However, I just added a Basic Firewall to bump up the security a bit, at least, now I can assume no remote access can connect directly to my DB instance.

I followed this thread

Jump to **Step Seven — Set Up a Basic Firewall** part of the post.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/initial-server-setup-with-ubuntu-16-04

---

Also, you can allow only some IP addresses to your DB instances. By following the instructions at https://www.linode.com/docs/security/firewalls/configure-firewall-with-ufw/#advanced-rules

I use this personally on my main instance where I trust connections would come only from one IP.

---

Hope this helps someone temporarily till a better fix emerges.

Comment: I will try this now. After closing ports and adding a password my database has been cleared once again. I hope this firewall works out.

Comment: @AndyNguyen I updated my post. Try the other link as well.

Answer (score 0):

Are your MongoDB password protected? if so, you can access the Database with only an IP address and the port.

If your MongoDB isn`t password protected, please do it asap! your info is exposed to everyone...

Even big companies do this mistake from time to time as well...